# Pandas get median/average of pre-aggregated data

Tags: pandas, median, grouped-table

Assuming my data is already grouped how can I calculate median and other statistics?

```
Index  Value  Count
0      6      2
1      2      3
2      9      8
```

In the example above I want to get the median/average etc of column Value taking into account the column 'Count'

The actual values are 2,2,2,6,6,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9 so my median would be 9.

Comment: You can use `df.median()` and `df.mean()` on your aggregated dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can do for the average

```
print ((df['Value']*df['Count']).sum()/df['Count'].sum())
6.923076923076923
```

and for the median, use [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html?highlight=repeat#numpy-repeat)

```
print (np.repeat(df['Value'], df['Count']).median())
9.0
```