# De-aggregate data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to figure out how to work with pre-aggregated data in pandas/matplotlib.
I'm extracting my data from Kibana/ElasticSearch, so it's not raw data it's already been aggregated into buckets.

Some example data looks like this (actual data has many more categories and buckets that go up to 40).

```
Category,Bucket,Count
A,0,134563
B,0,215777
C,0,149918
A,1,183394
B,1,430333
C,1,234846
A,2,301137
B,2,604825
C,2,369665
A,3,385299
B,3,638058
C,3,471866
```

I realized since the data is already aggregated, I can't use any distribution plots, but I can plot the above data in a generic bar chart to see the distribution.  That works.

What I want to do now is pull out stats like mean/median (per Category) and other stats from `describe()`, and also plot these on a boxplot.

How can I "de-aggregate" my data or otherwise transform it back to raw data so that I can more naturally work with it?

I got a hint from [Pandas get median/average of pre-aggregated data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61845056/pandas-get-median-average-of-pre-aggregated-data) about using `np.repeat()` to expand my counts back to raw data.  My counts are way too high for that but I figure I can divide by 10 or 100 to get a reasonable approximation.

So I think I understand what I want to do, I just can't make np/pandas pull this off.

```
np.repeat(df['Bucket'], df['Count'] / 10).describe()

count    411961.000000
mean          1.914108
std           1.023361
min           0.000000
25%           1.000000
50%           2.000000
75%           3.000000
max           3.000000

# Think that's working?  But now how do I break it down by Category?
byCat = df.groupby('Category')
np.repeat(byCat['Bucket'], byCat['Count'] / 10).describe()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'SeriesGroupBy' and 'int'
```

Comment: Do you really have to disaggregate the data? All of those values can be calculated by considering the number of observations as the weights. There's a whole post on how to calculate weighted percentiles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844024/weighted-percentile-using-numpy and the statsmodels library has an entire part dedicated to weighted statistics https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.DescrStatsW.html. Sure you can `repeat` for smaller datasets, but it becomes infeasible for larger data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib boxplot using precalculated (summary) statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655798/matplotlib-boxplot-using-precalculated-summary-statistics)

Comment: Maybe `pd.pivot_table('Count', index='Bucket', columns='Category')` is helpful?  It is hard to get means if you don't have any values to start from.

Answer (score 0):

You could group by Category and then calculate the statistics for each:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

for cat, df_cat in df.groupby('Category'):
    print(f'\nCategory: {cat}')
    print(np.repeat(df_cat['Bucket'], df_cat['Count'] / 10).describe())
```

Output:

```
Category: A
count    100437.000000
mean          1.933072
std           1.047681
min           0.000000
25%           1.000000
50%           2.000000
75%           3.000000
max           3.000000
Name: Bucket, dtype: float64

Category: B
count    188897.000000
mean          1.881512
std           1.004221
min           0.000000
25%           1.000000
50%           2.000000
75%           3.000000
max           3.000000
Name: Bucket, dtype: float64

Category: C
count    122627.000000
mean          1.948788
std           1.030864
min           0.000000
25%           1.000000
50%           2.000000
75%           3.000000
max           3.000000
Name: Bucket, dtype: float64
```